# iOS Webservice Results to Array

Tags: ios, web-services

I use a webservice to take information. When I take string result, I can not write it into an array.

In foundCharacters when I write `NSLog(@"%@",string);` it writes all values correctly but when I write:

```
[myArray addObject:string];
NSLog(@"%@",myArray);
```

I see lots of nulls. How can I take these values and write them into an array :(

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{

    [datawebservice setLength:0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

    [datawebservice appendData:data];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

    xmlparserr = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:datawebservice];
    [xmlparserr setDelegate:self];
    [xmlparserr parse];



}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    elementyedek = elementName;

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{


    if ([elementyedek isEqualToString:@"StokAdi"]) {
       [myArray addObject:string];

        NSLog(@"%@",myArray);       

    }


}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    NSLog(@"ERROR with theConnection");
}
```

Comment: nulls like nil, or nulls like NSNulls?

Comment: How are you initializing myArray?

Comment: i am initializing in ViewDidLoad

Comment: try instantiating myArray in `connectionDidFinishLoading`

Comment: when i write array nslog in viewdidload it seems null again. :(